# How install Toggl Desktop in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation

How can install Desktop Toggl on Ubuntu 13.04?
I try type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:official-toggl/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install desktop-Toggl
```

But getting information desktop-Toggl not found.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Instructions for Ubuntu 64-bits

According to [this note in the PPA's project](https://launchpad.net/toggl-desktop), the ppa was deprecated:

> Toggl Desktop in launchpad is now deprecated. We have a new version out which can be downloaded here: http://support.toggl.com/toggl-on-my-desktop/

Luckily, they are providing a deb package ready to install in their [GitHub repository](https://github.com/toggl/toggldesktop#linux-1). **You need to install certain dependencies and use Ubuntu 64 bits**. This won't work in Ubuntu 32-bits.

```
sudo apt-get install libc6 libdrm2 libexpat1 libffi6 libgcc1 libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa libglib2.0-0 libgstreamer0.10-0 libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 liblzma5 liborc-0.4-0 libpcre3 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxau6 libxcb1 libxcb-dri2-0 libxcb-dri3-0 libxcb-glx0 libxcb-present0 libxcb-sync1 libxcomposite1 libxdamage1 libxdmcp6 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxml2 libxrender1 libxshmfence1 libxslt1.1 libxss1 libxxf86vm1 zlib1g
cd ~/Downloads
sudo dpkg -i toggldesktop*.deb
```

"Why installing all those packages if the only dependency is libxssl?" you may ask. Simply, because the binary needs all of them. If you run `ldd ToggleDesktop` on the binary you may find:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff8cdfc000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007fd4e1779000)
libXss.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXss.so.1 (0x00007fd4e1576000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fd4df716000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fd4df40b000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fd4df1f4000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd4dee4b000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007fd4dd7f0000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fd4dd5eb000)
libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007fd4dd3d9000)
libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fd4da4b9000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fd4da1aa000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fd4d9ea9000)
libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0x00007fd4d9c0e000)
libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fd4d9263000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fd4d905b000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fd4e1fa7000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007fd4d858d000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007fd4d8387000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fd4d816c000)
libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007fd4d7f62000)
libXcomposite.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcomposite.so.1 (0x00007fd4d7d5f000)
libxslt.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxslt.so.1 (0x00007fd4d7b1f000)
libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007fd4d77ba000)
libgstreamer-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-0.10.so.0 (0x00007fd4d74c9000)
libgstapp-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstapp-0.10.so.0 (0x00007fd4d72bb000)
libgstbase-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstbase-0.10.so.0 (0x00007fd4d7061000)
libgstinterfaces-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstinterfaces-0.10.so.0 (0x00007fd4d6e4e000)
libgstpbutils-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstpbutils-0.10.so.0 (0x00007fd4d6c28000)
libgstvideo-0.10.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstvideo-0.10.so.0 (0x00007fd4d6a0b000)
libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007fd4d57b8000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007fd4d554a000)
libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007fd4d5320000)
libglapi.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0 (0x00007fd4d50f6000)
libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007fd4d4ef3000)
libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007fd4d4cec000)
libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0x00007fd4d4aea000)
libxcb-glx.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0 (0x00007fd4d48d1000)
libxcb-dri2.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri2.so.0 (0x00007fd4d46cb000)
libxcb-dri3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri3.so.0 (0x00007fd4d44c8000)
libxcb-present.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-present.so.0 (0x00007fd4d42c5000)
libxcb-sync.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-sync.so.1 (0x00007fd4d40bd000)
libxshmfence.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxshmfence.so.1 (0x00007fd4d3ebb000)
libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0x00007fd4d3cb5000)
libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2 (0x00007fd4d3aa7000)
liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007fd4d2018000)
libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fd4d1e14000)
liborc-0.4.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liborc-0.4.so.0 (0x00007fd4d1b8f000)
```

All those libraries weren't included in the package "Depends" field, but the binary needs all of them.

---

There's another option if you want to use the application without installing it in your system, in which case you need to download the binaries packages from [this](http://support.toggl.com/toggl-on-my-desktop/) page, download the Linux version using a browser (wget and curl seems to fail to do this). The file will normally be downloaded into your `~/Downloads` directory. Uncompress the files:

```
$ ~/Downloads
$ tar xzf toggldesktop_*.tgz
$ ls
cacert.pem  iconengines  imageformats  lib  platforms
```

Now make sure that the following packages are already installed:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6 libdrm2 libexpat1 libffi6 libgcc1 libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa libglib2.0-0 libgstreamer0.10-0 libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 liblzma5 liborc-0.4-0 libpcre3 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxau6 libxcb1 libxcb-dri2-0 libxcb-dri3-0 libxcb-glx0 libxcb-present0 libxcb-sync1 libxcomposite1 libxdamage1 libxdmcp6 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxml2 libxrender1 libxshmfence1 libxslt1.1 libxss1 libxxf86vm1 zlib1g
```

Once this is done, just run `./TogglDesktop` and ready.

### Important notes from the installation page:

- Toggl Desktop has been tested with Unity, Gnome and KDE in general should be working. There are known issues with LXDE.
- At the moment there is only 64bit binary package available. 32bit version is planned. There are no distribution-specific packages available.

> We don’t have a version for 32bit Linux, but you’re able to create it by following the instructions here: https://github.com/toggl/toggldesktop
>
> They are working on adding a generic .deb package which should be usable on all (recent) Debian based distributions.
>
> Currently, Toggl Desktop is only tested on Ubuntu. Most probably all recent Debian-based distributions will work, but they are untested.
>
> Starting from Ubuntu 13.04 there is no tray (notification area icon) support.

Comment: That's bad! only 64bit! I'm still on 32

Comment: `dpkg -i` first and then `sudo apt install -f` also works.

Answer (score 4):

## Ubuntu 16.04

Download from https://support.toggl.com/toggl-on-my-desktop/

```
tar -vzxf ~/Downloads/toggldesktop_linux_x86_64-{VERSION}.tar.gz

sudo apt-get update && apt-get install libgstreamer0.10-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev

~/Downloads/toggldesktop/TogglDesktop.sh
```

Note: Use `Linux tarball` to download `.tar.gz` and `Linux deb` for `.deb`

Answer (score 1):

I first installed Toggl without reading this question.

```
sudo dpkg -i toggldesktop_7.4.528_amd64.deb
```

After installation, there was dependency error, then I searched on it.
Finally I came here. But the installation steps seemed complex for me.

So I solved simply like this:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Download from:

- [deb package x64](https://toggl.com/api/v8/installer?app=td&platform=deb64&channel=stable) or
- [tarball](https://toggl.com/api/v8/installer?app=td&platform=linux&channel=stable)

No here is the catch, to run Toggl on Ubuntu 18.04 the dependency that you will need is `libgstreamer0.10-0`.

```
mbaric@i7 /mnt/podaci/Download $ sudo dpkg -i toggldesktop_7.4.122_amd64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package toggldesktop.
(Reading database ... 249888 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack toggldesktop_7.4.122_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking toggldesktop (7.4.122) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of toggldesktop:
 toggldesktop depends on libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0; however:
  Package libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 is not installed.
 toggldesktop depends on libgstreamer0.10-0; however:
  Package libgstreamer0.10-0 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package toggldesktop (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 toggldesktop
```

Since this package is not avaialble straight out of the box or on the repositories/PPA's that the come with regular install of Ubuntu.

So run next commands in your terminal:

```
wget http://hr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gst-plugins-base0.10/libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0_0.10.36-1_amd64.deb
wget http://hr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gstreamer0.10/libgstreamer0.10-0_0.10.36-1.5ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libgstreamer*.deb
```

Then let's re-run the installation of Toggl:

```
sudo dpkg -i toggldesktop_7.4.184_amd64.deb
```

Of course watch out for version that you downloaded, at the time I am writing this it's this one: `toggldesktop_7.4.184_amd64.deb`

Finally we run either in terminal: `/opt/toggldesktop/TogglDesktop.sh` or search for Toggle inside `Show Applications and run Toggl`

[image]
[image]

Have fun and I wish you smooth installation.

Taken and add my comments orginally from: https://support.toggl.com/desktop-apps/toggl-desktop-for-linux